# What is concept behind CAP#1 in generic (wild-card) JAVA?

Tags: java, generics, parameter-passing, wildcard

Consider the following example:

```
class First<T >
{
  T s;
  First(T s)
  {
        this.s=s;
  }
  void setS(T s)
  {
        this.s=s;
  }
  void getS()
  {
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}

class Use
{
        public static void setFirst(First<?>f)
        {
                f.setS(7);
        }
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                First <Integer> f4 = new First<Integer>(5);
                f4.getS(); 
                setFirst(f4);                   
        }
}
```

I know that compiler will give an error because write specific operations are not allowed in a method whose formal parameter is using wild-card for generics. Compiler error is:

```
gyan@ns:~/codes/java/generics$ javac -Xdiags:verbose *.java
Use.java:5: error: method setS in class First<T> cannot be applied to given types;
        f.setS(7);
         ^
  required: CAP#1
  found: int
  reason: argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to CAP#1
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class First
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
1 error
gyan@ns:~/codes/java/generics$
```

It is looking like CAP#1 is a data-type. I don't know any thing about this concept. Please help.

Comment: See [*Wildcard Capture and Helper Methods*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `<?>` represent unknown type i.e. `List<?>` means list of unknown type so nothing can be added to it except null as compiler can't verify the type on addition.

However, you can change the parameter type to `<Integer>` or `<? super Integer>` to make that method work:

```
public static void setFirst(First<Integer> f) {
    f.setS(7);
}
```

Refer: [wildcards in generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Answer (score 0):

In generics everything is replaced just at Compile time to provide type Safety.

In your example, the compiler processes the `f` input parameter as being of type `Object`. When the `setFirst(First<?>f)` method invokes `f.setS(7);` the compiler is not able to confirm the type of object that is being  initialized into and an error is produced.

When this type of error occurs it typically means that the compiler believes that you are assigning the wrong type to a variable. Generics were added to the Java language to enforce type safety at compile time.

```
public static void setFirst(First<?>f) // at compile time no special type parameter found. So No Replacement will take place.
        {
                f.setS(7); //confusing case because it not a type Parameter should be replace with any Java Class not the Constant.
        }
```

But Here in other cases in main

```
First <Integer> f4 = new First<Integer>(5); // T is replaced with Integer.
 f4.getS(); // It will produce 5
 setFirst(f4);  // it will also get executed because of f4 is a object of First<Integer>.
```